# How to use my android phone as a webcam, microphone and a speaker when video calling on skype?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, android, skype, webcam

I have Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS on my laptop. Its audio port and webcam are not working(damaged). I can't use Skype on my phone for video calling since since Skype can't use proxy settings on unrooted devices. So when using Skype on Ubuntu, I want to use my phone's camera as a webcam, its microphone as a microphone for my laptop and its speaker(earphones inserted into the audio port of my phone) as a headset. How can I do this? Can I do this wirelessly or should USB be preferred? I have USB 2.0 ports on my laptop and Android Marshmallow on phone.

Answer (score 3):

You can try DroidCam https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev47apps.droidcam, but in the long run it's probably best to buy an external Webcam.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: Link works here...

Comment: Link also works here... Just go to the play store and search for DroidCam

Comment: I had to disable uMatrix to get the link too work. My bad. Can this app use the microphone of my phone and audio jack while using Skype on Ubuntu?